# When my friend starts his laptop, our connectivity to Internet becomes slow

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

We have a Wi-Fi router with through which we both connect to Internet. But when my friend starts his laptop, after sometime, Internet becomes slow. Why? How should I fix this?
There is no torrent or other download manager running in the background in his laptop.
Operating System: Windows  Vista.
Wi-Fi router: Linksys

**Update**: I ran tcpview on his computer, there was one btdna.exe. It was something BitTorrent related process. May it be the problem? There was no torrent leeching/downloading from his computer, though.

Comment: Can you tell your friend to turn his laptop off right now? The Internet seems slow to me...  (Sorry-- couldn't resist...)

Comment: Does the problem go away when you stop the btdna service or uninstall bittorrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [posting here](http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1180689.htm#post4415417) the btdna.exe process may indeed use excessive amounts of network and other resources.  The recommendation here and on other process analyzing sites is that it should be safe to stop this process.  To stop it from startup, you should be able to use the utilities in [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to disable the entry ([directions here](http://docs.piriform.com/ccleaner/using-ccleaner/managing-auto-starting-programs)).
Also, as the other posters have mentioned, run a virus/malware scan just to be sure there's nothing else running around.

Answer (score 4):

Is there spyware spam software running on his laptop?

Comment: how do I check this? tcpview?

Comment: Try booting a livecd perhaps?  If the issue shows up when you have booted to a clean environment then you can be pretty sure something about his install is messed up.

Comment: +1 I also think this is the problem. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the network traffic on his laptop by running a packet sniffer like wireshark on it. That should tell you what is going on, but not what program is generating all the traffic. If you see lots of packets but cannot figure out what they mean or why they are there, call tech support or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by running a mal/spyware scan using something like ASquared Free or a similar program. I usually start by running a clean with CCleaner (It wipes out the temp folders were malware usually spawns from) and then rebooting and following with a deep spyware scan.